# Reactive content

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to change the choices of a updateSelectizeInput on server.R depending on the values a user entered on a textInput on ui.R.

**Extract from server.R:**

*Update ZIPCode with NewZIP entered by user*

`isolate({if (input$NewZIP != "") {ZIPCode<-reactive(input$NewZIP)}})`

*Fetch file associated with ZIPCode and update the choices of a dependent pull down list*

`ZIPFile<-read.csv(paste0("./data/",ZIPCode), sep="")
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'MedicalProcedure', server = T, 
                         choices=as.character(ZIPFile$a_description))`

This doesn't work and I can't figure out where I did something wrong.

Can somebody help?

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isolate` is supposed to be used **inside** a `reactive`: it makes the `reactive` 'insensitive' to `input` changes inside. So you should try something like this:

```
ZIPCode <- reactive({
    if(input$NewZip == "") return(NULL)
    input$NewZip
})

ZIPFile <- reactive({
    if(is.null(ZIPCode())) return(NULL)
    read.csv(paste0("./data/", ZIPCode()), sep="")
)}

observeEvent(ZIPFile(), {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'MedicalProcedure', server = T, 
                         choices = as.character(ZIPFile()$a_description))
}, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
```